# File format change in linux

Tags: linux, file, format

I have a file abcd.csv in linux system which is in ": UTF-8 Unicode English text, with CRLF, CR line terminators"  I need to convert it to ": UTF-8 Unicode English text, with CRLF line terminators"

please suggest

I tried dos2unix as well as perl -pi -e 's/\n/\r\n/' no Luck please suggest.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

`CRLF, CR line terminators` means that the first line of the file has a `CRLF` line ending and the following (to the sample distance I assume) have `CR`, like this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{prinf "foo\r\nbar\rbaz\r"}' > test
$ file test
test: ASCII text, with CRLF, CR line terminators
```

We can see that with `less -U test`:

```
foo^M
bar^Mbaz^M
```

Using GNU awk to convert it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r\n?";ORS="\r\n"}1' test > out
```

Test it with `file`:

```
$ file out
out: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

or `less -U`:

```
foo^M
bar^M
baz^M
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance it helps, In my end nothing has been modified in application that generate files or the script that used to process the file for past 6 months, on of the sudden we started seeing files getting created as "": UTF-8 Unicode English text, with CRLF, CR line terminators" instead of "": UTF-8 Unicode English text, with CRLF" any suggestion what to be checked here. its in linux machine